# Display images on Joomla

Tags: joomla

I just can't seem to display my images in Joomla. Here is an example of my code:

```
<a href="/img/Zaalvoetbaltornooi SKLA 2.jpg" rel="shadowbox"><img src="/img/Zaalvoetbaltornooi SKLA 2.jpg" width="200px" height="250px" alt="Fuif SLKA" id="eventskla" />
```

As you can see it also uses shadowbox which doesn't work. Here is a screenshot of my folders:

[image]

And a screenshot of templateDetails.XML:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Options in Joomla wrong or wrong code?

Comment: Do those images exist? What happens if you call them manually in your browser? (`http://yourdomain/img/Zaalvoetbaltornooi SKLA 2.jpg`)

Comment: It says: 404 - Category not found. I'm new to Joomla. Do I have to upload them another way than via de template manager? All the images you see in the screenshot have been uploaded via the template manager...

Comment: I don't know Joomla either, but it seems like something is wrong with the image directory configuration...

Answer (score 3):

I found it: I used the 'normal' way of coding but the code you have to use is this one:

`<img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/images/myimage.png" alt="Custom image" class="customImage" />`

Then simply change the map and image (e.g. /img/base.jpg) you're using in Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a friendly tip, I like to create a variable called "tpath", which is the path to the template. It makes the paths I have to write in the template much shorter. I just create the variable in the Head like so:

```
$tpath = $this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template;
```

Now all you have to do to write a template URL is:

```
href="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/...
```